# Can someone explain following type casting in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, casting, type-conversion

I've following piece of code.
What I am trying to understand is, why are we type-casting with `*(uint8 *)` instead of just `*(uint8_t)`?

- Isn't `*(uint8_t *)value` read as: `value` is ptr to `uint8_t` ptr and
- Isn't `*(uint8_t)value` read as: `value` is ptr to `uint8_t`

I'm just a little confused by the two. Any explanation is much appreciated.

```
uint8_t  read_8_function(uint8_t *addr);
uint16_t read_16_function(uint16_t *addr);
uint32_t read_32_function(uint32_t *addr);

int some_function(uint32_t size, uint32_t *value){

    uintptr_t some_addr = (uintptr_t *)0xaaaa5555;

    switch(size) {
        case 1:
               *(uint8_t *)value = read_8_function(some_addr);
        case 2:
               *(uint16_t *)value = read_16_function(some_addr);
        case 4:
               *value = read_32_function(some_addr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first `*` is not part of the typecast.

Comment: The casting will mean that only a *part* of `value` will be written to. Exactly which depends on platform. It also breaks *strict aliasing*.

Comment: And where did you get this code from? How is this function used? It just seems... Well, *bad*.

Comment: Usually you use `void *` if you want to pass a generic pointer to a function.

Comment: it's a mock up piece of code, I am just trying to understand the conceptual difference between ```*(uint8_t *) ``` vs ```*(unint8_t)```.

Comment: The cast `(uint8_t *) value` casts `value` into the type `uint8_t *`, which is a pointer that can be dereferenced. The cast `(uint8_t) value` cast the pointer `value` to an `uint8_t` *value*, which is not a pointer and can't be dereferenced. You might want to take a step back, and refresh your knowledge of pointers and related operators (like the dereference operator `*`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yeah i guess I need to get a refresher on pointers. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is a pointer to `uint32_t`. The cast converts it to a pointer to a different type; `(uint8_t *)value` converts it to a pointer to `uint8_t`. Then dereferencing that is used to assign to an 8-byte field at that address.

`(uint8_t)value` would convert the pointer into an 8-bit integer. Then putting `*` before that would try to use that integer as the address to assign to, which is not valid; you can't dereference an integer. Also, pointers are bigger than 8 bits (they're either 32 or 64 bits on most modern CPUs), so converting the pointer to `uint8_t` would discard most of the pointer's value.